# Excel VBA/Macro to hide all rows except top 5 rows and selected row?

Tags: excel, vba

good afternoon, everyone. I have several worksheets in progress that have various rows of data in the field. I have one aspect of unhiding all of the rows through a macro, as well as creating VBA to select and hide all rows without colored squares from within the worksheet. My main dilemma is that in a section with let's say 200 rows, I want to have it so that only the row the user has selected through the cursor and the top 5 rows (Or maybe just the top row or so, depending on the table.)

Any help would be appreciated. I'll post an example of what I mean.
`like so`
Title 1 Title 2 Title 3

Row 1 Something 1 SomethingElse 1

Row 2 Something 2 SomethingElse 2

Row 3 Something 3 SomethingElse 3

**Row 4** Something 4 SomethingElse 4 <User is on Cell A, shown here as Bolded

Row 5 Something 5 SomethingElse 5

Row 6 Something 6 SomethingElse 6

Row 7 Something 7 SomethingElse 7

Row 8 Something 8 SomethingElse 8

Row 9 Something 9 SomethingElse 9

Row 10 Something 10 SomethingElse 10

This is what I'd Like after the macro gets done. Just the top row and selected row.

Title 1 Title 2 Title 3

Row 4 Something 4 SomethingElse 4

Thank you again, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

### Show Top Rows(s) and Selected Row(s)

- Copy the code into the sheet module of the worksheet where you want this to happen.
- With the current setup, it shows (unhides) the top row and the rows of the selected cells in column `A`.
- Adjust (play with) the values in the constants section.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sCols As String = "A" ' or e.g. "A:E"
    Const fRows As String = "1" ' or e.g. "1:5"
    
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(Columns(sCols), Target)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then
        Rows.Hidden = False
    Else
        
        Dim frg As Range: Set frg = Rows(fRows)
        Dim drg As Range: Set drg = frg
        
        Dim iRow As Range
        
        For Each iRow In irg.Rows
            Set drg = Union(drg, iRow)
        Next iRow
        
        Rows.Hidden = True
        drg.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = frg.Row
    
    End If
 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. However, I get an error upon trying to run the code as a active x button: Run-Time error'1004': Unable to set the hidden property of the range class

Comment: The code is written for the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event so it will get triggered automatically. You'll have to share how you plan to use it with a command button e.g. the modified code, where it is (in which module, worksheet, workbook...), where is the button... etc. This occurring error is often fixed with 'slipping in' an `EntireRow` e.g. `Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = ...`. Hard to tell without the additional details.

Comment: I understand. Apologies. I wanted to use this code as a form control at first, but upon selecting the macro, it wouldn't appear. So I then started using it as a active x control and was able to select the code, but then the error appeared. I plan on using it on three sheets seperately where they'll have similar functions, but with different parameters (one sheet has 37 rows and the other is close 1000, for example.) The error does highlight the Rows.hidden = true line, even after slipping in the entirerow section, if that provides more info as well.